# How to open and find the number of words within a file with a list of strings in different txt files

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, moodle

I have to create a function named processFiles that takes a list of strings(list of filenames) as a parameter. The function should open each print the total number of words in all of the files in list of filenames on one line and the average number of words per file on the following line.

I'm completely confused as to where I even start. This is what I have to do(this is just an example):

list of filenames is equal to ['input1.txt','input2.txt','input3.txt']

with the above files containing the following information:

imput1.txt contains the words The quick brown fox
input2.txt contains the words jumped over
input3.txt contains the words the lazy dog

Your function should print:
9 for word total
3 for word average

Comment: What difficulty are you having in doing so that someone can help with? Do you know how to open a file, read a line, split a string, loop over lists? That's all the bits you need to put together to do this...

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. You can look at my answer it should implement your use case. But for the future please consider adding code, show us what you've already tried. [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

For instance you can do it like so:

```
files = ["foo.txt", "bar.txt"]

def proces_files(files):
    for f in files:
        print("Processing file {0:s}".format(f))
        with open(f, "r") as f:
            content = f.readlines()
            total = 0
            for index, line in enumerate(content):
                words = line.split(" ")
                total += len(words)
                print(
                    "Total number of words: {0:d} in line {1:d}".format(
                        len(words),
                        index + 1,
                    )
                )

            avg = (total / len(content))
            print("Average quantity of words per line {0:d}".format(avg))

proces_files(files)
```

First you have to read each file provided in a list

1. For each file read its lines with `readlines()` function
2. For each line count words length by splitting line by space `split(" ")`
3. Print words count and on which line it is (use [`enumerate()`](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/enumerate.html) to keep track of index)
4. Increment total amounts of words
5. Count and print average
6. Next iteration

Sample output:

```
Processing file foo.txt
Total number of words: 3 in line 1
Total number of words: 2 in line 2
Total number of words: 4 in line 3
Average quantity of words per line 3
Processing file bar.txt
Total number of words: 4 in line 1
Total number of words: 2 in line 2
Average quantity of words per line 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read all the files consequently and append their content to a list. Then evaluate the number of words in the list.

```
files = ['input1.txt', 'input2.txt', 'input3.txt]
l = []
num_files = 0;
for file in files:
    with open(file) as f:
        l.append(f.readlines())
        num_files += 1

num_of_words = len(str(l).split())
print(num_of_words)
avg = num_of_words/num_files     //average
```

Comment: i tried to use it i think its correct but its giving me an error saying myFile = open(listOfFileNames,"r")
TypeError: invalid file: ['input1.txt', 'input2.txt', 'input3.txt']